# A bunch of unclear things with the destructor in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

I've written some very simple code in C++ to do some simple manipulations of vectors. This is the content of the file vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define VECTOR_H_INCLUDED

class Vector {
    int *coordinates;
    int *size;
public:
    Vector(int vector_size);
    Vector(int*,int);
    ~Vector();
    void print(void);
    Vector operator +(Vector);
};
#endif
```

and this is the implementation (file: vector.cpp):

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Vector::Vector(int vector_size) {
    coordinates = new int[vector_size];
    size = new int;
    *size = vector_size;
}

Vector::Vector(int* vector_coordinates, int vector_size){
    coordinates = vector_coordinates;
    size = new int;
    *size = vector_size;
}

void Vector::print(void){
    cout << "[";
    for (unsigned short int index =0; index<*size; index++){
        cout << coordinates[index];
        if (index < *size-1){cout << ", ";};
    }
    cout << "]\n";
}

Vector Vector::operator+ (Vector other) {
  Vector temp(*(other.size));
  if ((*temp.size)!=(*(this->size))){
      throw 100;
  }
  int* temp_c = new int[*(other.size)];
  int* other_c = other.coordinates;
  for (unsigned short int index =0; index<*size; index++){
    temp_c[index] = coordinates[index] + other_c[index];
  }
  temp.coordinates = temp_c;
  return (temp);
}

Vector::~Vector(){
    delete[] coordinates;
    delete size;
}
```

From my main.cpp, I do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "vector/vector.h"

const int size = 3;

int main() {
    int *xxx = new int[size];
    xxx[0]=4; xxx[1]=5; xxx[2]=-6;


    Vector v(xxx,size);// v = [4, 5, -6]
    Vector w(size);// w is a vector of size 3

    w = v+v; // w should be w=[8,10,-12]
    w.print();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is then:

[148836464, 5, -6, 17, 148836384, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 17, 3, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 17, 148836480, 0, 0, 17, 0, 10, -12, 135025, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, , 0, 0,Segmentation fault

If I remove the two lines from the destructor:

```
delete[] coordinates;
delete size;
```

everything works as expected and the program outputs:

```
[8, 10, -12]
```

I would appreciate any explanations...

**Update 1:** I changed my operator+ method to the following, but the problem was not resolved:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(Vector other) {
    int size_of_other = *(other.size);
    int size_of_me = *(this->size);
    if (size_of_other != size_of_me) {
        throw 100;
    }
    int* temp_c = new int[size_of_me];
    int* other_c = other.coordinates;
    for (unsigned short int index = 0; index < size_of_me; index++) {
        temp_c[index] = coordinates[index] + other_c[index];
    }
    Vector temp(temp_c,size_of_me);
    return (temp);
}
```

**Update 2:** I noticed that using the operator:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(Vector other);
```

I wouldn't get the desired result. The modification that made it work was:

```
const Vector& Vector::operator+(const Vector& other) {
    Vector temp(other.size);
    for (unsigned short int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        cout << "("<< index <<") "<<coordinates[index] << "+"
                        <<other.coordinates[index] << ", "<< endl;
        temp.coordinates[index] = coordinates[index] + other.coordinates[index];
    }
    return (temp);
}
```

**Update 3:** After update #2, I was getting a warning from the compiler that I return the local 'temp'. I changed my code to the following which completely resolved all problems and works fine (I return a *copy* of temp):

```
const Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& other) const{
    Vector temp(other.size);
    for (unsigned short int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        temp.coordinates[index] = coordinates[index] + other.coordinates[index];
    }
    return *(new Vector(temp));
}
```

Comment: `delete [] coordinates;`

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I corrected that. But, again... the same! I'll update it in my question.

Comment: There is no reason for the member `size` to be a pointer.  Pointers make your job harder.

Comment: using `std::unique_ptr` would have highlighted several of your errors.

Comment: Just posted a full working implementation including copy constructors and assignment operators which I've verified works. Check it out for a look at what we've all been suggesting...

Comment: Consider using a `std::vector` to store your `coordinates`. Management will be a lot easier and require a lot less code.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Vector::operator+` has at least one bug:

```
int* temp_c = new int;
...
    temp_c[index] =
```

You are indexing `temp_c` when it was allocated with only a single integer. So your loop is stomping on some other memory, causing undefined behaviour.

You will also need to define a *copy constructor* so that you can properly use your `Vector` objects. The compiler generates a default copy constructor, but the default one is generally not suitable for objects that contain pointers.

This line:

```
temp.coordinates = temp_c;
```

causes a memory leak, because it overwrites the previously allocated `temp.coordinates` vector.

**Update 3**: Your code

```
return *(new Vector(temp));
```

while it appears to work, is still a memory leak. You are allocating a new `Vector`, then the compiler calls the copy constructor to copy that into the return value of your function. Nobody ever `delete`s the `Vector` object you just created, so there is a memory leak.

The solution is to **write a copy constructor**, instead of relying on the compiler-generated default copy constructor. All the other answers to your question have said the same thing. It is required that you do this for a correct program.

Comment: You're right! I'll update my question. Unfortunately, it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: What about defining a copy constructor? Did that help?

Comment: May I have an example on how to use the copy constructor in this context. I believe what I did (see update 1 in my question) should be equivalent to the copy constructor. Isn't it?

Comment: No, you actually need a real copy constructor. The copy constructor requires a signature of `Vector(const Vector &)` and will construct a new `Vector` based on a *copy* of the contents of its argument. You will also want to define an *assignment operator* which does even more work.

Comment: +1 for copy constructors and pointers. The default copy constructor will only to a shallow copy and doesn't understand what's on the heap...

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to work correctly.  A big hint that they are needed is that the destructor is not `{}`.  See the "[Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)".

To get a bit better and more modern, you could also consider a move constructor and move assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below which:

1. Implements a default constructor. This garauntees that however your object is constructed, your internal variables are going to be pointing at something on the heap or at `NULL` so any `delete []` calls aren't going to die horribly.
2. Implements a copy constructor. Default copy constructors don't copy memory on the heap so that was going to be a serious problem for you.
3. Implements an assignment operator. Again this avoids shallow copies.
4. Removes size as a pointer; On most systems, pointers are the same size as integers so making size a pointer just makes things unnecessarily complicated.
5. Fixes the addition constructor by avoiding intermediate allocations. You had a temporary local variable there so make use of it instead of allocating several extra intermediate objects.

...take a look:

```
// VectorImplementation.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Vector {
    int *coordinates;
    int size;

public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int vector_size);
    Vector(int*,int);
    Vector(const Vector& v);

    ~Vector();

    Vector operator +(Vector);
    Vector& operator =(const Vector & other);

    void print(void);
};

Vector::Vector() {
    coordinates = NULL;
    size = NULL;
}

Vector::Vector(int vector_size) {
    coordinates = new int[vector_size];
    size = vector_size;
}

Vector::Vector(int* vector_coordinates, int vector_size){
    coordinates = vector_coordinates;
    size = vector_size;
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& v) {
    size = v.size;
    coordinates = new int[size];
    memcpy(coordinates,v.coordinates, sizeof(int)*size);
}

void Vector::print(void){
    cout << "[";
    for (unsigned short int index =0; index<size; index++){
        cout << coordinates[index];
        if (index < size-1){cout << ", ";};
    }
    cout << "]\n";
}

Vector Vector::operator+ (Vector other) {
  Vector temp(other.size);
  for (unsigned short int index =0; index<size; index++){
      temp.coordinates[index] = coordinates[index] + other.coordinates[index];
  }
  return (temp);
}

Vector & Vector::operator= (const Vector & other)
{
  if (this != &other) // protect against invalid self-assignment
  {
    // 1: allocate new memory and copy the elements
    int * tmp_coordinates = new int[other.size];
    memcpy(tmp_coordinates, other.coordinates, sizeof(int)*other.size);

    // 2: deallocate old memory
    delete [] coordinates;

    // 3: assign the new memory to the object
    coordinates = tmp_coordinates;
    size = other.size;
  }
  // by convention, always return *this
  return *this;
}

Vector::~Vector(){
    printf("Destructing %p\n", this);
    delete[] coordinates;
}

const int size = 3;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int *xxx = new int[size];
    xxx[0]=4; 
    xxx[1]=5; 
    xxx[2]=-6;

    Vector v(xxx,size);// v = [4, 5, -6]
    Vector w(size);// w is a vector of size 3

    w = v+v; // w should be w=[8,10,-12]
    w.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It really works. The program invokes the destructor twice when executing the line "w = v + v;". None of the destroyed instances is v or w. I guess one of them is temp inside operator+. But what is the other one?

Comment: If the compiler does not optimize things there can be two objects destroyed. One is the temp constructed in + operator. On return a new object is constructed by the copy constructor for the temporary object that holds v + v (+ operator returns by value)

Answer (score 0):

Doing that is a bad idea:

```
Vector::Vector(int* vector_coordinates, int vector_size){
    coordinates = vector_coordinates;
    size = new int;
    *size = vector_size;
}
```

you assign coordinates pointer to data that you did not allocate, and then try to delete it in the destructor.

But the real reason that you get segfault is that you use the default copy constructor, and the temporary copy of v deletes the vector when it dies. You have to implement copy constructor and ensure deep copy or reference counting.

Try something like this:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& other){
    size = new int(*other.size);
    coordinates = new int[size];
    memcpy(coordinates, other.coordinates, sizeof(int)*(*size));
}
```

Also, your operator+ would be much more efficient if you take const reference as an argument:

```
 Vector Vector::operator+ (const Vector& other)
```

Comment: I use int* for dynamic allocation of memory for the coordinates since their size might vary. I could surely use int for the size of the vector, but the purpose of the whole thing is for me to understand a few things on C++...

Comment: That's ok for coordinates, but size should be an int field, not a pointer

Comment: True. However, I believe my update-#1 is equivalent, isn't it?

Comment: I think you mean update #2 - yes that's what I meant.
But this change only avoids copying when using operator+. It increases speed (so you should do it), but regarding your problem, it only avoids it, doesn't solve it. You still need to implement copy constructor and operator= to get rid of the problem.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: Your Update3 is a very bad idea. It's asking yourself for memory leaks. Please change your signature of operator+ to the one I provided in the answer. You should take a const reference as an argument, but return by value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line

```
w = v+v; // w should be w=[8,10,-12]
```

a temporary object is constructed for the result of v+v, then assigned to w and destroyed.
Since you don't have and assignment operator a shallow copy is performed by the default implementation and you are working with deallocated memory.

The simple way to fix this issue is to implement a copy constructor/ assignment operator and destructor when you are allocating memory for members.

Comment: So, whenever I do "w=v", what the compiler really does is "w=*(new Vector(v))" where Vector(v) should be explicitly declared and implemented otherwise some default copy-constructor is used over which we don't have full control?